# Django admin panel cannot be edited

Tags: python, django-models

```
class Quiz(models.Model): 
    """ This is table of quiz. """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)

    @property
    def quiz_questions(self):
        num_of_questions = Question.objects.filter(quiz = self).count()
        return num_of_questions
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.code:
            self.code = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters+string.digits, 20))
            super(Quiz, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When edit existing title in admin panel, it is not changing!